# Getting Intra-Frames from a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

First, let me preface this with saying that I have to process a massive amount of videos and shaving even 1 second per video is very significant.

I'm trying to extract the position of all intra-frames in a video.

FFProbe works, but it's amazingly slow.

FFMpeg works much faster, but it's still quite slow.

So, my question is if there is a lib, where I could do something like this pseudo code:

```
var frame = first_frame;
do
{
    if (frame.type == intra_frame) log(frame.time);
    frame = frame.next;
} while (frame != null);
```

and scan through the video very fast, not looking at anything inside the frames, but just the headers to find the type of the frame and move on to the next.

The end goal is to generate filmstrips, for preview, as fast as possible. I need to generate 48 thumbnails roughly evenly spread through the movie and covering the whole movie span (excluding 5 sec on each end). I am hoping to speed the process up by extracting only intra-frames. Since I need a fixed number of thumbnails, I can only do this by knowing the total amount of intra-frames.

This scenario works only if the time to find all the intra-frame indices and extract 48 intra frames is less than getting frames, in a single pass, at regular intervals, 48 times.

---

Edit: This is the solution I have found so far; in this example I take one frame every minute

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -skip_frame nokey -i _a.mp4 -vf "select='eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)*(lt(abs(t\-30)\,2)+lt(abs(t\-90)\,2)+lt(abs(t\-150)\,2)+lt(abs(t\-180)\,2)+lt(abs(t\-240)\,2)+lt(abs(t\-300)\,2)+lt(abs(t\-360)\,2)+lt(abs(t\-420)\,2))',showinfo,scale=640:480,tile=6x8" -vsync 0 frames.jpg
```

I found that if I specify the frames directly, I don't really get a speed difference.

Short of going through the API, is there anything faster with FFMPEG?

Comment: You can do this heuristically. Read the number of entries in the `stss` box. Probe the duration of the media. Calculate a rough KF distance value, in seconds. Use ffmpeg with`-skip_frame nokey ` and select filter to extract frames which are roughly that far apart. Add `-vframes 48` to avoid extra images.

Answer (score 0):

In the general sense, no, such a lib does not exist. But you could approximate the results if you make assumptions based on the specific videos you deal with. FFmpeg can not do that for you since it is a generalized framework.

Let's start simple:

- what container are your videos?
- what codec do they use?

Why do I ask this? Some containers (e.g. AVI) mark frame type in the index, so you don't need to do anything with the compressed frames to get the information you're asking for. For other containers (e.g. Matroska/WebM), the information is not strictly part of the container, but derivative information is present. For example, for compressed streams that are not intra-only (e.g. H.264/VP9), the seekHead is - in practice - a list of keyframe positions, similar in scope to the index in AVI files. But this is not guaranteed by the spec, it just happens to be true in practice.

OK, so let's say the container isn't sufficient for your purposes. You'll need to parse the video data yourself. For H.264, you could parse the slice header of the first slice in each frame to get the slice type. All following slices (for the same field) are guaranteed by spec to have the same slice type. This could be I, B or P. If it's I, it's an intra frame. For VP9, the header has fields called keyframe and intraonly that do what you're looking for. Other compression standards (MPEG-1/2/4, HEVC, VP8, etc.) are the same, but you'll need to implement this yourself. It's not complex, but there are no generalized frameworks that do this for you since it's a very non-obvious use case.

Comment: we have mp4 containers, but there is unfortunately a lot of variation between the video since they're user user submitted, which I why I don't want to directly parse the format. Let me edit the question to explain the end goal, maybe other solutions will popup.

Comment: mp4 also has keyframe markers, so that should work just fine. See "sc->keyframes[]" in libavformat/mov.c and how that's used to set AVINDEX_KEYFRAME in the index. The index is generated during read_header() so this should be accessible from the ffmpeg API without writing your own mp4 parser, and still be codec-agnostic.

Comment: that's very interesting. I'm looking into this right now.